# How to use JSONPath to filter JSON body with nested arrays

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

This is the JSON Path I have been using:

`$..products[?(@.category == 'merchant_cards' && @.countries[0].abbr == 'US' && @.skus[0].min < '25')]`

However, I am getting an error `end of input expected at 1:12`

Here is an excerpt of the body:

```
[
  {
    "id": "ACGZXBCIGX8Y",
    "name": "Overstock.com",
    "currency_codes": [
      "USD"
    ],
    "skus": [
      {
        "min": 5,
        "max": 500
      }
    ],
    "countries": [
      {
        "abbr": "US"
      }
    ],
    "category": "merchant_cards",
    "disclosure": "",
    "description": "",
    "images": [
      {
        "src": "https://giftrocket-s3.imgix.net/Brands/US/Overstock/Digital/Overstock.png",
        "type": "card"
      }
    ]
  },
```

I want to be able to filter on some nested lists and that seems to be causing the problems.

For example, I want only those in the US.  `countries` is a list of one, which has a node of `abbr` which can have multiple values.

Comment: Looks like the `JSON` is invalid and not the `JSONPath`. Always try to include a valid JSON though it's an excerpt of the body. Use https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Yeah I can update it, it's just the original output is so large

Answer (score 1):

When I complete the json array, this works:

```
$[?(@.category == 'merchant_cards' && @.countries[0].abbr == 'US' && @.skus[0].min < 25)]
```

I also changed the min limit to an int.

Try it on https://jsonpath.com/

Comment: thanks, let me try again, how are you testing it?  jsonlint?

Comment: jsonlint is for validating your json and not jsonpath. Use jsonpath.com for jsonpath testing

Comment: See updated answer, @satchel